# Facebook style message inbox

Tags: php, sql

Am creating a messaging system model after facebook's messages.
The message inbox is threaded, but am having issues with my query for viewing for a message and other messages exchanged in thread.
db tables look like this.

messages

- mid
- seq
- created_on
- created_by
- body

messag_recips

- mid
- seq
- uid
- status

Note: the MID column is the message ID. Think of each initial message as the beginning of a thread. Instead of having unique message IDs that are all parent/children, I decided to have one main thread (MID) and then have messages in it – which are all defined by the SEQ (sequence number) column. The rest is pretty self explanatory. The created_by and all subsequent user identifications will be numeric ID’s that may point to a different user ID somewhere else. The last thing to note is that the primary key is based on the MID and the SEQ – you will never have more than one entry per MID/SEQ. 
STATUS column – which will be N for new, A for active (or read) and D for deleted

this is my query

```
$sql = "select m.mid, m.seq, m.created_on, m.created_by, m.body, r.status from message_recips r
                inner join messages m on m.mid=r.mid and m.seq=r.seq
                where r.uid='$uid' and m.mid='$mid' and r.status in ('A', 'N')";
```

but it returns only messages sent to the current user, i want it to return message also sent by the current user. How should i modify the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to get both messages sent to the current user, as well as messages sent by the current user... an OR relationship.

Try this:

```
where (r.uid='$uid' OR m.created_by='$uid') and m.mid='$mid' and r.status in ('A', 'N')";
```